Complex types definition: Abstract method filter
I have been struggling to build two kind of type definitions helpers, a bit like Omit<...>, InstanceType<...>, etc.
I'll give one here:
abstract class C {
    abstract abstr(): void
    method() {}
}

I'm looking to make a definition AbstractMethod<C> for example who would retrieve, in this case, only 'abstr'
I'm not even sure either is possible
PS: Of course, any variant like this would be doing the job:
ConcretePart<C> giving
{
    method: ()=> void
}

EDIT:
Use case: https://github.com/emedware/flat-diamond#abstraction
If two classes have concurrent definitions (one abstract, one not), I was trying for only the "concrete" one to be kept in the type definition (for now, I use "first one" policy)

Seems like Typescript doesn't have a way to check if a given property is abstract or not.

This isn't possible, the abstract modifier can't be manipulated/detected at the type level. I don't even see requests for this in GitHub anywhere, so it doesn't seem to be a common thing for people to want. That makes me suspect this might be an XY problem: what is your use case?

Looking at that link, you're... reinventing mixins? And the default behavior of how abstract class instance types combine isn't sufficient for you? How does the implementation resolve the situation at runtime? If the default behavior of TS when combining abstracts doesn't work for you, I'm inclined to think this is just impossible and you might want to file a feature request in GitHub with as self-contained of a use case as possible (that is, it shouldn't just be a link to your github repo). I could write this up as an answer but I'm not sure it's worthwhile.
